# How to change dashing shortenedNumber suffix

Tags: dashing

I am using dashing.

The standard suffix of shortenedNumber is K. 
How and where to change this?

I looked for the file dashing.coffee (where i think this could be changed) but did not found this..

Comment: Are you talking about 'Rickshaw' widget?

Comment: No sam. You may find the K Suffix in a meter Widget

Comment: Sorry, Hank. Never saw it use 'K' suffix for Meter or for that matter even Graph.